# How to interpret a noninformative joint prior?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, prior

I am currently working on a homework assignment and have the following question:

$\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are parameters of interest and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the likelihood functions which are $\text{Bin}$~$(n_1, \theta_1)$ and $\text{Bin}$~$(n_2, \theta_2)$ respectively.

It is known that:

1. Both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are independent.
2. $P(\theta_1, \theta_2) \propto 1$ and is bounded.

I am currently struggling on interpreting what it means that $P(\theta_1, \theta_2) \propto 1$, especially in identifying the marginal priors for this.

My perspective is that since $P(\theta_1, \theta_2) \propto 1$ is a non-informative prior, it suggests that they do not value-add in terms of beliefs to the overall posterior distribution (i.e. the likelihood function is responsible for the update in beliefs). Since the joint prior is non-informative in this sense, the marginal prior must also be non-informative.

Comment: $\propto 1$ is a uniform distribution. If you have a uniform distribution for the joint distribution, then the marginal distributions will be uniform as well.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is exactly about. *"... a non-informative prior, it suggests that they do not value-add in terms of beliefs to the overall posterior distribution ... "* yes that is the idea behind non-informative. ('weakly informative' might be a better term than 'non informative')

Comment: There is no non-informative prior: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27835/7224