# What is the correct calculation for AIC corrected (AICc) for a bagged random forest model using the Boston Housing data set?

Tags: r, random-forest, aic, bagging

This question of calculating AIC was answered for a specific linear model here: [Calculating AIC “by hand” in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87345/calculating-aic-by-hand-in-r)

The problem and solution for a linear model are as follows:

```r
lm_mtcars <- lm(mpg ~ drat, data = mtcars)
```

Solution as presented to calculate AIC for that specific linear problem:

```r
nrow(mtcars)*(log(2*pi) + 1 + 
    log((sum(lm_mtcars$residuals^2)/nrow(mtcars)))) + 
    ((length(lm_mtcars$coefficients)+1)*2)
```

However, I'd like to calculate AICc for a number of different models, and most of them do not have an easy way to return an AICc value, starting with a bagged random forest, using the Boston Housing data set.

The corrected part of the AICc formula is: $(2k^2 + 2k)/(n-k-1)$ where $n$ is the sample size, and $k$ is the number of parameters (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#Modification_for_small_sample_size)

Is this the correct way to calculate AICc in this situation, given what we know above?

```r
library(MASS) # gives the Boston Housing data set
library(e1071) # to tune the random forest model
df <- MASS::Boston

bag.rf.test.aic_c <- 0 # set initial value to 0
bag.rf.test.aic_c.mean <- 0 # set initial value to 0

for (i in 1:10) {
  idx <- sample(seq(1, 2), size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE, 
                prob = c(0.6, 0.4))
  train <- df[idx == 1,]
  test <- df[idx == 2,]
  
  bag.rf.tune <- e1071::tune.randomForest(x = train, y = train$medv, 
                       mtry = ncol(train)-1)
  
  bag.rf.test.aic_c[i] <- nrow(test)*(log(2*pi) + 1 + 
    log((sum(bag.rf.df$residuals^2)/nrow(test)))) + 
((length(bag.rf.tune$best.model)+1)*2) + (((2*ncol(test)**2) + 
    2*ncol(test))/(nrow(test) - ncol(test) -1))
  bag.rf.test.aic_c.mean <- mean(bag.rf.test.aic_c)
}

bag.rf.test.aic_c.mean # returns the mean value
bag.rf.test.aic_c # returns each of the values
```

This returns a value of mean value of 16.02185 for the AICc, but this function returns a very wide range of values for bag.rf.test.aic_c: 7.416128, -4.396740,  7.416128, 29.618431, 32.776451, 26.414226, 32.776451, 14.281003, 23.164508, -9.248086

What is the correct way to calculate AICc in this situation?

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Akaike Information Criteria applied on Random Forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/486572/7515)