# Bayesian linear model vs classical linear model

Tags: bayesian, linear-model

My question is a quite general and simple question.

I was wondering what is the advantage of a bayesian linear model over a classical linear model if, for the bayesian model, only non-informative priors are used?

Shouldn't be more or less the same?

What I mean by linear model is the well-known model that links an observation vector of dependent variables $\mathbf{Y}$ of size $n$ and a matrix $\mathbf{X}$ (design matrix) containing the information about independent variable of size $n\times p$, $p\leq n$, such that
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\theta,
$$
where $\theta$ is the parameter to be optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bayesian linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/252577/bayes-regression-how-is-it-done-in-comparison-to-standard-regression/252608#252608) *is* the same as linear regression. If you find the parameters of linear regression with maximum likelihood, the difference in the case of a Bayesian flavor is that it would also consider the priors. You are asking about uninformative priors, but there is [no such a thing as "uninformative" prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20520/what-is-an-uninformative-prior-can-we-ever-have-one-with-truly-no-information). Every prior does affect the result, some just do this only slightly. The exception would be if you used constant, improper prior $p(\theta) \propto 1$, that would not affect the result, and the Bayesian maximum a posteriori estimate would be equal to the maximum likelihood result.

Your second question about the advantages of using a Bayesian model with uninformative priors is answered in the [Why would someone use a Bayesian approach with a 'noninformative' improper prior instead of the classical approach?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27589/why-would-someone-use-a-bayesian-approach-with-a-noninformative-improper-prior) thread.

Comment: Super, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You get the Bayesian interpretation of your parameters + any other benefits/features of a Bayesian approach. Numerically, everything will be the same (or very similar)

Comment: Except you shouldn't interpret e.g. CrIs as containing the true value with a given probability, unless you have coherently used all available prior information.